# Datable duplicating inside modal when chrome back button hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables, bootstrap-modal

Without going too much into detail. I am designing my own e-learning platform.

[image]

everything works fine. I hit "view more classes" under my math box and this modal pops up normally. I would then hit a class link in the datatable and then if i hit the chrome back button i get the above. I am sure how this piece of code is the culprit:

```js
$('.table').DataTable( {

        scrollCollapse: true,
        bFilter: false,
        order: [], 
        searching: true


    });
```

Why would something like this happen? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Just in case anyone was curious, it turns out that turbolinks was the real culprit. I removed them and everything is fine now. I am using Ruby on Rails.